# Xpages: Getting all values from ViewColumn and comparing the values

Tags: javascript, dojo, xpages, lotus-notes

i am using lotus notes 9 and trying to get all values from a View Column for comparing if any of them are different and if any of them are different to pop out a messagebox of the result right now i tried

```
var tmp = ""
var tmp2 = false

dojo.query("#viewColumnHeader2").forEach(
                function(obj)
                {
                    if (tmp == "")
                    {
                        tmp = obj.getValue
                    } 
                    else
                    {
                        if(tmp != obj.getValue)
                        {
                            var check = true
                            tmp = obj.getValue
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            var check = false
                            tmp = obj.getValue
                        }
                    }
                    if(check == true)
                    {
                        var tmp2 = true
                    }
                }
            )

if(tmp2 == true)
{
    var result = window.confirm("Message")
}
```

viewColumnHeader2 is my id for the viewcolumn that i set in All Properties but seems it has not been assigned anywhere in html code but i have a feeling i am going in the wrong direction
i am doing this in CSJS

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use CSJS, add a style class on that column's values and retrieve them via that. But you will only get the column values for the entries on that page, not the whole view.

Depending on what you're trying to do, SSJS / Java may be better.